# Smooth animation between tabs when using selector - Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-tablayout, material-components-android, material-components

I would like to get the background of the tab animated smoothly to the selected position (just like the default `tabIndicator` animates between tabs).

Here is how my `TabLayout` looks like

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_layout_bg"         
    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
        app:tabIndicator="@null"
        app:tabRippleColor="@null">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab1"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab2"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab3"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

[image]

Here, `Tab 3` is selected. If i select `Tab 1` the background should animate from `Tab 3` to `Tab 1`.

I am using selector to change the background of the tabs.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_layout_fg"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_layout_bg"/>
</selector>
```

Here i am attaching the sample animation. See just the tab bar.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this kind of animation with approach i am following? If not please suggest me another way. I have been working on this from two days. Still can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your requirement for `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: try these libraries [dk-tablayout](https://github.com/dueeeke/dk-tablayout) or [NavigationTabStrip](https://github.com/Devlight/NavigationTabStrip)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We've achieved the same effect in our app using TabLayout.

[image]

***The trick for smooth animation is to use tabIndicator attirbute instead of tabBackground!***

You can define a shape drawable (not selector) and assign it to TabLayout by:

```
app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_layout_fg"
```

This will add a tab indicator with smooth animation that you want to achieve.
If you find that tabIndicator color is not reflecting as defined in the drawable file, you can tint the tabIndicator using **tabIndicatorColor** attribute.

**Note: Make sure you're using latest design support library v28.0.0 or material components library for Android X.**

Comment: Combining your answer and @Gabriele answer worked for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 22):

Check the @Maulik answer. It is what you are looking for.
Just to integrate the answer, without a custom shape (in your example you are using it) you can just use:

```
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
      app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
      app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/...."
      ..>
```

The [`INDICATOR_GRAVITY_STRETCH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.html#indicator_gravity_stretch) allows you to stretch the tab selection indicator across the entire height and width. In this way you can just use the `app:tabIndicatorColor` without drawable to set the selected color used.
The animation is provided by default.

Comment: If i don't use the custom shape i am not getting rounded corners. I had to use app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_layout_fg"
app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch" 
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
to make it work as i wanted. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Praveen I know it. I indicated that the Maulik answer is what you are looking for. It is just to integrate the answer.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti how can we set different drawable for each tab ? For center tab I want rectangle and for first and last it should be curved.