# How to tab indicator expand and contract dynamically - android studio

Tags: android, tabs, indicator

I would like the tab indicator to first expand and then contract when sliding from one side to the other, like in the image, any ideas? Thank you very much

[image: The image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question, it may be useful [Smooth animation between tabs when using selector - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084965/smooth-animation-between-tabs-when-using-selector-android).

Also, there are some libraries that may help you:

[Android tab animation](https://github.com/cats-oss/android-tab-animation)

[SmartTabLayout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout)

[Dachshund Tab Layout](https://github.com/Andy671/Dachshund-Tab-Layout)